# Load data only once with useFirestoreConnect

Tags: firebase, react-redux-firebase, redux-firestore

I am using useFirestoreConnect hook to get data from collections and need data from collection only once.

But on official documentation [here](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore.html), There is no mention of turning off listeners. due to which my daily free quota exceeds sometime.

Is it possible to load data only once with useFirestoreConnect?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Unmount component to stop the listener.

> useFirestoreConnect is a React hook that manages attaching and
> detaching listeners for you as the component mounts and unmounts.

https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/firestore

Option 2: Make the query with useFirestore()

```
const firestore = useFirestore();
var docRef = firestore.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then((doc) => {
     if (doc.exists) {
     console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
     } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
     }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/api/useFirestore.html

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document